# Eigen C++: mapping a raw buffer for a Sparse Matrix

Tags: c++, buffer, sparse-matrix, eigen

I have some troubles with mapping a raw buffer for a SparseMatrix.

1 - No problem for the Non Sparse Matrix Case with the following code:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd DIFFXX;
new (&DIFFXX) Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> (&coeff_diffxx(0,0), coeff_diffxx.xsize(), coeff_diffxx.ysize());
```

2-  I failed when I want to do the same kind of operation for a SparseMatrix

i) this way:The resulting MAA is completely wrong

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, Eigen::RowMajor> MAA;
new (&MAA) Eigen::Map< Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, Eigen::RowMajor>> (xsize*ysize, xsize*ysize, 3*xsize*ysize, tridiagonalMatrix.outerIndexPtr(), tridiagonalMatrix.innerIndexPtr(), &m_a.m_data[1]);
```

ii) or this way: MAA is not referencing `&m_a.m_data[1]` but copying it !

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, Eigen::RowMajor> MAA = Eigen::Map< Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, Eigen::RowMajor>> (xsize*ysize, xsize*ysize, 3*xsize*ysize, tridiagonalMatrix.outerIndexPtr(), tridiagonalMatrix.innerIndexPtr(), &m_a.m_data[1]);
```

My aim is to perform operations with sparse (tridiagonal indeed) matrices on C++ raw buffers.

Thanks for any hint.
Luc

Comment: Can you try creating the map like this?

`Eigen::Map< Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, Eigen::RowMajor>> MAA(xsize*ysize, xsize*ysize, 3*xsize*ysize, tridiagonalMatrix.outerIndexPtr(), tridiagonalMatrix.innerIndexPtr(), &m_a.m_data[1]);`

Also, are you pointing to `m_a.m_data[1]` intentionally, or should you be pointing to `m_a.m_data[0]`?

Comment: Hi. I am pointing to [1] intentionally. Regarding your proposal, I already tested it. And it works well, indeed. But afterwards, I am unable to perform some matrix operations such as adding to MAA another SparseMatrix, while this was easily doable with mere DenseMatrix.

Comment: You should not use placement-new to different types. The `Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd>` only "works", because these types share a common memory layout (but it will likely fail when storage gets re-allocated). The result of adding two sparse matrices should be stored in a `SparseMatrix`, getting the result into a `Map<SparseMatrix>` is nearly impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it with the class *MappedSparseMatrix*, this way:

```
int outerPtr[] = {0,2};
int innerPtr[] = {1,2};
double valsPtr[] = {2.5,3.6};
Eigen::MappedSparseMatrix<double, Eigen::ColMajor, int> mat(5,1,2,outerPtr,innerPtr,valsPtr);
```

Thanks !